# element.$server is undefined when passing data from java to javascript in vaadin 14

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, rpc

I'm trying to interact between Vaadin and amcharts. Basically I need to draw a map using amcharts libraries, and when I click on the map I need to send back information about the click to Java. My problem is that I can't figure out how to properly interact between the two, with the documentation showing very simple examples.

In the vaadin docs it shows an example like:

```
getElement().executeJS("jsMethodName($0)", getElement());
```

and then to send back data to Java:

```
element.$server.javaMethodName(args);
```

My problem is that I can send from Java to JS correctly, and the element is loaded correctly. But when I do `element.$server.javaMethodName()`, `element.$server` is always undefined. I don't understand if I'm missing something or if I dind't understand the correct way to use this.

This is my Java method:

```
    @ClientCallable
    private void clickBullet(String area) {

        log.error("Clicked area: " + area);
    }
```

and this is the call from JS:

```
function clickBullet(name, element) {
        if(element !== null){
            element.$server.clickBullet(name);
        }
        else {
            console.log("element is null");
        }

    }
```

Note that element is not null, it is correct.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that `element` is something else than what you expect it to be? You can add `debugger;` at your JS function and it will stop at a breakpoint there automatically.

Comment: @ollitietavainen maybe, I'll try. One thing that is not clear to me is if the element from which you call `executeJS` must be the same that you pass as an argument. Otherwise I guess you wouldn't be able to find the Java function (?). I don't know.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the JavaDoc of Element.executeJS and Element.callJSFunction?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this sorted ? I'm having a very similar issue as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74135342/vaadin-flow-javascript-to-java-call/74143417#74143417

Comment: @Sergiu Hi, it's been more than I year so I don't recall the actual solution I found, I know I managed to make it work and I'm looking now at the code to try and remember. One thing I did was to pass the element as a variable before, and then execute the server side call passing that element, instead of passing it directly. So something like `getElement().executeJs("myElement = $0;", getElement());` and then use the variable `myElement` in the `element.$server` code. I'm sorry I can't be more useful, I really don't remember exactly what it was.

Comment: I know it's kinda hacky and surely there are better ways, I just know it worked so that's fine by me.

Comment: @LucaTrecarichi thanks for the input, I will try and see if what you suggested works. I was able to pass the element to the Javascript side of things but unfortunately I never have a $server  variable on the element, it is always "undefined".