# Vaadin flow javascript to Java call

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

Following this tutorial https://vaadin.com/blog/calling-java-from-javascript I'm trying to call a Java function from javascript but that doesn't seem to work as expected.

I'm having a View that contains a button which, on its onClick handler, triggers a call to a Javascript function, which works as expected.

The problem I'm having is that the getElement() that I`m passing to the javascript function is undefined when it reaches the javascript side of things.

My code looks as follows:

```
@JavaScript("./js/script.js")
public class RouteGraphicsView extends Div {
....
        Button b = new Button("Test Button");
        b.addClickListener(new ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onComponentEvent(final ClickEvent<Button> event) {
                UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("greet($0, $1)", "test name", UI.getCurrent().getElement());
            }
        });
....
}
```

The above call reaches the script.js file which looks like this

```
window.greet = function greet(name, element) {
    console.log("Hello, I am greeting you, " + name);
    
    try {
        console.log("Element ", element);
        console.log("Logging 1", element.$server);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

The output shown by the greet function above is

```
Hello, I am greeting you, test name
vaadin-bundle-62ac8b…b56c6.cache.js:4813 Element  
vaadin-bundle-62ac8b…b56c6.cache.js:4813 Logging 1 undefined
```

Since the element.$server is undefined I can not get the javascript function to call my greet function in the View, which is annotated with `@ClientCallable`

```
@ClientCallable
public void greet(final String name) {
    System.out.println("Called from JavaScript: " + name + " \n\n\n");
}
```

I've tried various other ways of calling the script.js, like using button's element to invoke the executeJs function or passing the button's element (b.getElement()) as an argument to the function but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `element.$server` on the element that you passed as `UI.getCurrent().getElement()`. This corresponds to the UI instance and not an instance of the `RouteGraphicsView` class that (I assume) has the `@ClientCallable` method. Using the button would also not work for the same reason.

You should pass an instance of the view, which in your case needs to be written as `RouteGraphicsView.this` because of the way the regular `this` refers to the click listener.

Comment: Leif, first of all thank you for answering.
Now, to clarify things a bit, yes, my @ClientCallable is within the RouteGraphicsView class.
The particular Vaadin version I'm running is 14.7.0 (if that's of any interest).

Secondly, there is a difference between what the tutorial is saying I should do for getting from Java to JavaScript. The tutorial says I should be doing `getElement().executeJavaScript` for calling the function in the .js file. When I try to do this nothing happens on the javascript side of things. It's only when I do UI.getCurrent().getElement().executeJs things start to go

Comment: Now, I tried your suggestion and changed the 

`UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("greet($0, $1)", "test name", UI.getCurrent().getElement());` 

to

`UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("greet($0, $1)", "test name", RouteGraphicsView.this);`

but without any luck. 
If you have any other suggestions I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: When I output the arguments that my greet function receives, the second one - e.g. the class instance of RouteGraphicsView is null while the first one (a simple String) is logged and received as expected.

Comment: There is a similar post to what I'm experiencing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192087/element-server-is-undefined-when-passing-data-from-java-to-javascript-in-vaadin

Comment: I assembled the different snippets into something that works as a whole by adding `@Route` to the class and `add(b);` to the constructor. With those small adjustments, the example works for me when I pass `RouteGraphicsView.this` as the second argument to `executeJs`. It shouldn't have any impact, but I used a different Vaadin version. You could try with the latest 14.x release, i.e. 14.8.20.

Comment: If `getElement().executeJavaScript` doesn't have any impact, then it sounds like the problem is that your component isn't properly attached. No idea what that means though since then the button would also be missing (though you're not showing the code that adds the button, so I don't know how that's supposed to be).

Comment: My class is not annotated with `@Route` since the routes are defined dynamically from a config file. Instead the routes are set in an `ApplicationServiceInitListener` the implements `VaadinServiceInitListener`.

Also, the views are not static but rather generated dynamically from the same config I'm referring to above. 

At this point I'm thinking that I'm not doing the js call in the proper view class... 
Thanks for your support!